# Titanium Appcelerator - Remote URL not showing up as background image to View

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

So here's a nice one.  I'm creating a imageView by doing this:

```html
var tagView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
 backgroundImage: 'http://www.travelandtourworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/google-logo.jpg',
 height:150,
 width:365,
 zIndex:10000
});
```

The problem is - anytime I use a remote URL as a background image it doesn't show up.  Has anyone run into this and is there a good workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a rough guess but does it work when you use a normal `View` instead of an `ImageView`? Or try the `image`-property instead of `backgroundImage`-property for the `ImageView`. I just think that a background image is not the best practice to do on an `ImageView` even though the docs say it's possible.

Comment: The image property works fine.  Unfortunately the issue comes in animating the imageView.  I'm doing a curl down on the image view - and with the image property set the image doesn't show until after the animation is complete.  Using background image works - but only for local files it seems.

Comment: Maybe it would be an option for you to wait for the `load` event to fire on the `ImageView` and then start the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some testing with this as well and also found that backgroundImage doesn't work for remote URLs.

I've sort of fixed it by hacking this code into TiUtils.m of the Appcelerator core (tested with 3.5.0.GA).

```
if (resultImage == nil) {
    if ([image isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSURL* imageURL = [TiUtils toURL:image relativeToURL:nil];
        resultImage = [[ImageLoader sharedLoader] loadRemote:imageURL];
    }
}
```